How do i fix Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
I am running a java program where it shows a JavaFX when I run the Main.java class. When I run the Main in my IntelliJ it works fine but after I build artifacts I can't run the jar file and get this error:

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I have tried adding a VM options which is
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-21.0.3\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml 

But when I add this and run the main class I get error. (Still can't run the jar file.)

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module sample.claimapp not found

So I am not sure how to fix this problem.
By the way, I use:
java -jar ClaimApp_jar.jar


If JavaFX is not included in the JAR file? Then you need to pass --module-path and --add-modules on the command line ("adding a VM options" only has an effect when running from your IDE/build tool). You can of course write a script to do this for you if you want. If JavaFX is included in the JAR file? Then make sure your main class and Application class are separate classes.

Another option is to deploy a self-contained application (see jlink / jpackage, GraalVM native image, etc.).

The module path is literally a list of directories which each contain modules (.jmod files or modular .jar files).  Your module path needs two entries:  the JavaFX SDK lib directory (which you already specify) and the directory where your own .jar file is located.  For example, --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-21.0.3\lib;C:\Users\Numi\projects\claimapp\target" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Currently 163 duplicates.

I figured out the Problem. I have to create a seperate Main class to run my main class. So I created a App.java class to run my main
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}

Then I changed the pom.xml file so mainClass is set to App. Then I created a new artifact by setting the main class to App.java

See also @Slaw's answer on this topic; the section Ignore the Warning may be relevant.
